# MailChimp API - how to bypass the review process

Tags: mailchimp

I am building a system that should send out nightly email reminders to my subscribers.  I've been asked to use Mailchimp as the email delivery service.  I've begun integration with the MailChimp API.  But it seems that every time I transmit email content and subscriber lists to mailchimp, it does not immediately get emailed.  Instead, someone still needs to login to mailchimp, manually review, assign subscriber list, publish and send the emails.

I can't figure out how to bypass this "staging" area in mailchimp, and just tell the API to immediately send my emails to my recipients.  Can anyone point me to the appropriate API calls that will do this?  I really want to use Mailchimp as an SMTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The reason MailChimp doesn't let me send emails directly because the process I'm interested in falls under the category of Transactional Emails, which are against the Terms of Service.

For Transactional Emails, I should be using Mandrill, which is the MailChimp SMTP server.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/how-to/transactional-campaigns.php