# How to add to MailChimp list using ChimpKit for iOS through api call without verifying email?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailchimp

I am using [ChimpKit 3.1.1](https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpKit3) for iOS in Objective C and can successfully add to my list. However, it sends a verification email to the user and they have to click a link before they're added.

Isn't there an api parameter you can send that skips this step?

Comment: is this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989756/mailchimp-api-how-to-bypass-the-review-process?rq=1

Comment: Almost, I just wasn't sure what parameter to include in the *params NSDictionary that you send to MailChimp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API Parameter you can use. For the [lists/subscribe](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) call in v2.0, it is a boolean param called 'double_optin'.

Looking at the [sample code for that library](https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpKit3), I assume you'd just add another param to the `*params` NSDictionary.

Be careful with this and only subscribe people who actually want to be on your list -- subscribing people who don't know why they're being subscribed can lead to spam complaints which can get you into trouble. When in doubt, double-optin is a pretty safe thing to do. Most folks who aren't willing to click a confirmation link probably don't really want to be on your list in the first place.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I tried it and it worked great. It's working for me using the "delegate method" code sample. One that I don't get are the error methods just below, I can't get them to show up without compiler errors.